# How do I download and install xlrd and mySQLdb for python 3.4.4

Tags: mysql-python

I am using python 3.4.4, stuck at the installation of xlrd and mySQLdb.I gone through the previous posts which suggest pymysql, but not getting the installation idea of pymysql as I am new to python.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 7